# Vue.js how to link two properties?

Tags: vue.js

In script section of component i have 2 properties: defaultConfig and items. Items - it is a property is used to create dynamic text fields. defaultConfig - it is a config which is resieved from the server. So i should link model with defaultConfig."some parameter".

I tried this code, but it doesn't work because defaultConfig is not available inside items and items.fields...

```
defaultConfig: null,
items: [
{
    header: 'Параметры генетического алгоритма',
    fields: [
    {
        placeholderText: 'Семя генератора случ. чисел', 
        type: 'text', 
        model: defaultConfig.GENERATOR_SEED
    },
},...
]
```

So what the way to do this thing?

Comment: Update `items` after receiving `defaultConfig` from your server ?

Comment: use ```this.defaultConfig.GENERATOR_SEED``` and update your items when the config is fetched from server and then render it

Comment: no, i render my fields with help of items before i have got defaultConfig

Comment: Consider moving both properties to `computed`. Functions can rely on each other much more stably than variables.